# Can I import a Receiving Address

Tags: bitcoin-core, receiving

I installed Bitcoin Core and a friend sent me 0.2 bitcoins using an address generated in Bitcoin Core.
However, Bitcoin Core fails to retrieve the Block Chain and keeps trying to reload; which takes days.
So I have never received the bitcoins.

I have the receiving address.
Can I use that in a different (hopefully more reliable ) wallet? e.g. Electrum.